# How to align contents in center into Webview

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I am showing some contents into a webview which starts with a `<p>` and ends with `</p>` tag. I am loading the content into webview by loadDataWithBaseURL and trying to show the contents in middle:

```
public static String contentPrefix = "<html><head><style type='text/css'>#content_wrapper {position: relative; margin: 0px auto;} </style></head><div id='content_wrapper'>";
public static String contentPostfix = "</div></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", contentPrefix + result + contentPostfix, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

But it is not working. What should I do to show that contents in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it works!

```
    String desiredContent = "my test html";
    String strBody = "<html>"
        + "<head>"
        + "     <style type=\"text/css\">"
        + "     @font-face "
        + "         {   font-family: Tahoma;"
        + "             src:url(\"~/android_asset/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf\") "
        + "         }"
        + "     #text"
        + "         {   font-family: Tahoma;"
        + "             font-size:14;"
        + "             text-align: center;"
        + "         }"
        + "     </style>"
        + ""
        + "</head>"
        + "<body dir=\"rtl\" id=\"text\">"
        + desiredContent 
        + " </body></html>  ";

myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, strBody, "text/html", "utf-8",
        null);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public static String contentPrefix = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">p{text-align:center;}</head>";
```